# How can I store php scripts on a server and execute them on other server?

Tags: php

I am trying to create a website which will ask another server(where i will put the main php scripts) for the scripts to execute on the current server.

Does anybody know how can I do such a thing?

Comment: WHY?? What are you trying to do?

Comment: You know, there are version control systems, for example `git`. Just with one row e.g. `git pull origin master` you can get all the latest code for your server.

Comment: You are going to need to be more specific about what you want to accomplish. If you just want to put PHP on one server and get info back from it, then yes you can do that and it's easy. If you want to store the files on server A, fetch them, and then execute them on server B...well, that's bizarre, and doable but not really easy - you'd need to use a file transfer protocol of some kind and configure server A to permit such behavior, and it would introduce lag, and it's just kind of a mess and best to avoid if you can.

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Yes, it's possible to store a script on one server and execute it on another, and there are even several ways you could do it. But whatever it is you're _actually_ trying to accomplish by doing so, there's almost certainly a better way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), but your sripts should be processed by webserver (Apache, PHP)